# Hard svg animation

Tags: animation, svg, css-animations

I need your help with the implementation of svg animation.
https://youtu.be/lrWjkARl8Zg
(sorry for the poor video quality)

And I have such a structure of svg

I need the arrow (class = "arrow") itself to move along long lines and draw it.

```html
 <svg class="vector" width="1193" height="329" viewBox="0 0 1193 329" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path class="long_line" d="M1436 327.98L84.7148 327.98C73.8082 328.219 62.9639 326.275 52.818 322.262C42.6722 318.249 33.4293 312.249 25.6315 304.613C17.8337 296.977 11.6384 287.858 7.40866 277.793C3.17891 267.728 0.999997 256.919 0.999996 246C0.999996 235.081 3.17891 224.272 7.40866 214.207C11.6384 204.142 17.8337 195.023 25.6315 187.387C33.4292 179.751 42.6722 173.75 52.818 169.738C62.9638 165.725 73.8082 163.781 84.7147 164.02L589.173 164.02" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
            <path class="arrow" d="M544 204L589 164L548 124" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
            <path class="arrow" d="M504 1L459 41L500 81" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
            <path class="short_line" d="M1308 41L459 41" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
        </svg>
```

Advise which library I can use

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using **svg smil animations**:
[A Guide to SVG Animations (SMIL)](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/#aa-animating-along-arbitrary-paths-the-animatemotion-element)

Your arrow animations could be achieved by
`<animateMotion>` for moving the arrow element and
animating the `stroke-dashoffset` property.

#### Animated example

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 33%;
  overflow: visible;
  display: block;
}

path {
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke: #000;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on animation for replay</p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1400 500">
  <defs>
    <path id="arrow" fill="none" d="M-45,40L0,0l-41-40" />
  </defs>
  <use id="arrow1" href="#arrow" />
  <use id="arrow2" href="#arrow" />

  <g id="graphics">
    <rect id="graphics" fill="#fff" fill-opacity="0" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <path id="mpath-long" fill="none" pathLength="100"  stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dashoffset="100" stroke-dasharray="100" d="M1571,413H219.7
    c-10.9,0.2-21.8-1.7-31.9-5.7c-10.1-4-19.4-10-27.2-17.6c-7.8-7.6-14-16.8-18.2-26.8S136,341.9,136,331s2.2-21.7,6.4-31.8
    s10.4-19.2,18.2-26.8c7.8-7.6,17-13.6,27.2-17.6c10.1-4,21-6,31.9-5.7h504.5" />
    <path id="mpath-short" fill="none" pathLength="100" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dashoffset="100" stroke-dasharray="100" d="M1443,126H594" />
  </g>

  <animateMotion href="#arrow1" dur="2" rotate="auto" repeatCount="1" begin="0;graphics.click" fill="freeze">
    <mpath href="#mpath-long" />
  </animateMotion>

  <animate attributeType="XML" href="#mpath-long" id="strokeAni" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="100" to="0" dur="2s" repeatCount="1" begin="0;graphics.click" fill="freeze" />

  <animateMotion href="#arrow2" dur="2s" rotate="auto" repeatCount="1" begin="0;graphics.click" fill="freeze">
    <mpath href="#mpath-short" />
  </animateMotion>

  <animate attributeType="XML" href="#mpath-short" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="100" to="0" dur="2s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" begin="0;graphics.click" />

</svg>
```

Quite likely, you will have to tweak your svg viewBox to get the desired result.
A common trick is to position element that's supposed to move along the motion path to x/y = 0.

#### Static example

```html
<style>
svg{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 33%;
  overflow:visible;
  display:block;
}

path{
  stroke-width:10;
  stroke: #000;
}
</style>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 1400 500">
  <defs>
    <path id="arrow" fill="none" d="M-45,40L0,0l-41-40" />
  </defs>
  <use id="arrow1" href="#arrow" />
  <use id="arrow2" href="#arrow" />
  <g id="graphics">
    <rect id="graphics" fill="#fff" fill-opacity="0" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <path id="mpath-long" fill="none" pathLength="100"  stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="100" d="M1571,413H219.7
    c-10.9,0.2-21.8-1.7-31.9-5.7c-10.1-4-19.4-10-27.2-17.6c-7.8-7.6-14-16.8-18.2-26.8S136,341.9,136,331s2.2-21.7,6.4-31.8
    s10.4-19.2,18.2-26.8c7.8-7.6,17-13.6,27.2-17.6c10.1-4,21-6,31.9-5.7h504.5" />
    <path id="mpath-short" fill="none" pathLength="100" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="100" d="M1443,126H594" />
  </g>
</svg>
```